# Modify text file with if-else statement

Tags: text-processing, awk, gawk

I have an input file like this:

```
3 1 10 1 6  
9 4 2  4 1  
9 2 2  2 1  
2 4 2  2 2  
9 4 9  2 9 1 2
```

The conditions that need to be followed:

1. If NF==5 and if $2 and $4 are the same then insert 11 in $3 location and in location $4, insert the value that is stored in $2 or $4 (here 1). The rest of the fields moves two locations to the right.
2. If NF==5 and if $1 and $3 are the same then in location $3, insert the value that is stored in $1 or $3 (here 2) and in location $4, insert 5. The rest of the fields moves two locations to the right.
3. The rest of the lines stay the same.

The output should look like this:

```
3 1 11 1 10 1 6    
9 4 11 4 2  4 1  
9 2 11 2 2  2 1  
2 4 2  5 2  2 2  
9 4 9  2 9 1 2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello @roaima, I figured out the solution. I made a silly mistake at the beginning. I'm adding the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{if((NF==5) && ($2 == $4)){$7=$5;$5=$3;$6=$4;$3=11;$4=$2;print $0}else if ((NF==5) && ($1 == $3)){$7=$5;$5=$3;$6=$4;$4=5;$3=$1;print }else{print $0}}' filename
```

output

```
3 1 11 1 10 1 6
9 4 11 4 2 4 1
9 2 11 2 2 2 1
2 4 2 5 2 2 2
9 4 9  2 9 1 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'NF==5{ if ($2==$4) $2 = $2 OFS 11 OFS $4; else if ($1==$3) $2 = $2 OFS $1 OFS 5 } 1' file
3 1 11 1 10 1 6
9 4 11 4 2 4 1
9 2 11 2 2 2 1
2 4 2 5 2 2 2
9 4 9  2 9 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the awk command in one-line that gives the required output:

awk '{if(NF == 5 && $2 == $4) {a=11; b=$2; print $1 " " $2 " " a " " b " " $3 " " $4 " " $5;} else if(NF == 5 && $1 == $3) {c=$1; d=5; print $1 " " $2 " "c " "d " "$3 " " $4 " " $5;} else  print $0}' sample_simple.txt